# Filter dataset to be queried later

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I'd like to query an eloquent model. Currently, this is how it's done:

```
$query = People::query()->where('something', '=', $something');
```

I'd like to add 3 dropdowns for the user to select what type of people he or she wants to find. These dropdowns would be `sex`, `hair color` and `body type`, all of them are of course optional. These values will also be in the query string if filled out.

This is what I tried to do:

```
if (Input::has('sex')) {
 $query = People::query()->where('sex', '=', $sex);
}
else
if (Input::has('sex') && Input::has('haircolor')) {
 $query = People::query()->where('sex', '=', Input::get('sex'))->where('hair_color', '=', Input::get('haircolor'));
}
else
if (Input::has('sex') && Input::has('bodytype')) {
 $query = People::query()->where('sex', '=', Input::get('sex'))->where('body_type', '=', Input::get('bodytype'));
}
else
if (Input::has('sex') && Input::has('haircolor') && Input::has('bodytype')) {
 $query = People::query()->where('sex', '=', Input::get('sex'))->where('hair_color', '=', Input::get('haircolor'))->where('body_type', '=', Input::get('bodytype'));
}
else {
 $query = People::query();
}
```

The main problem with this, apart from being *very* ugly spaghetti code is that the first condition almost always matches, so it's not accurate.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done sooo much simpler. Just add the wheres conditionally to your query:

```
$query = People::query();

if(Input::has('sex')){
    $query->where('sex', Input::get('sex'));
}
if(Input::has('bodytype')){
    $query->where('body_type', Input::get('bodytype'));
}
if(Input::has('haircolor')){
    $query->where('hair_color', Input::get('haircolor'));
}

$results = $query->get();
```

A few notes:

1. `query()` is only necessary if you want to "start" a new query on a model but don't have anything (a where, order by, limit etc) to apply. You could do `People::where(...)` without any problem
2. The `=` in the where statements can be omitted. Laravel will choose `=` as default operator if only two arguments are passed

---

If you were to name input parameters and db columns the same you could even do something like this:

```
$filters = Input::only('sex', 'body_type', 'hair_color');
$query = People::query();
foreach($filters as $key => $value){
    $query->where($key, $value);
}
$results = $query->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = People::query();
if (Input::has('sex')) {
    $query = $query->andWhere('sex', '=', $sex);
}
if (Input::has('haircolor')) {
    $query = $query->andWhere('hair_color', '=', Input::get('haircolor'));
}
if (Input::has('bodytype')) {
    $query = $query->andWhere('body_type', '=', Input::get('bodytype'));
}
```

you don't have to implement all of situations